# Stripe JS 3D Secure 2 test cards work but 3D Secure test cards do not work

Tags: stripe-payments, vuejs3, laravel-9, laravel-cashier

I am implementing a checkout page using Laravel and Vue.js. Test cards that don't require 3D Secure work well (e.g. 4242 4242 4242 4242). Test cards that require the customer to complete 3D Secure 2 authentication (e.g. 4000000000003220) also work(The pop up shows up after I call the confirmCardSetup method).

However, test cards that require the customer to complete 3D Secure (not 3D Secure 2) authentication (e.g. 4000000000003063) don't bring the pop up after calling the confirmCardSetup method. They are then subsequently declined on my backend with error

```
Your card was declined. This transaction requires authentication.
```

Here is my confirmCardSetup method which is supposed to bring up the pop up.

```js
const result = await this.stripe.confirmCardSetup(
  this.intentToken.client_secret,
  {
    payment_method: {
      card: this.cardElement,
      billing_details: {
        name: this.frontUser.name,
      },
    }
  }
);
```

I have tried adding off_session to false. I have also tried setting request_three_d_secure to 'any' with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who might come across this.

As long as card 4000000000003220 and card 4242424242424242 work in the test environment. The 3ds pop up will show up in live mode.

Answer (score 1):

Your setup seems to be correct. There are many test cards that trigger various behavior, some of them are for legacy configurations. If you make sure [cards from this list](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web#web-test-the-integration) work as intended, you can be confident that Stripe will display the 3D Secure pop-up when required.

I also managed to trigger the 3DS pop-up show for *3063 card. For that you need to [go here to your Dashboard](https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/radar) (or [here in test mode](https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/settings/radar)) and enable “Use Radar on payment methods saved for future use”. However, this is not required for testing your Setup Intent setup.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe if I could get the *3063 card working I will figure the rest out. I enabled Radar in test mode but it still doesn't trigger the pop up. On my client side, after calling confirmCardSetup with the client_secret, the setup_intent object returns with a status of 'succeeded' but no pop up and it it still fails in the backend with the message 'Your card was declined' when I charge. I should mention that this is a single charge not a subscription. What is your process like? Do you create a setupintent on the server first, and then use the client_secret to call confirmCardSetup ?

Comment: Your integration is correct. I am following [the official guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web), starting by creating a SetupIntent on the backend and then collecting the payment method on the client with `confirmCardSetup()` and `client_secret`. And if the Radar setting is enabled in test mode, I do see a 3DS popup.

Again, I want to stress that the behavior of the legacy test card your are using (*3063) with 3DS and SetupIntent is inconsistent. Therefore, I advise you to rely on test cards from this list I provided in the answer, and not worry about the rest.